# ¿Volley Comó saber cuando la pila ya realizo todas las peticiones?

Tags: android-studio, webservice, android-asynctask, android-volley

Estoy trabajando con Volley estoy haciendo peticiones constantes a un servidor y quiero que cuando ya haya terminado de hacer todas estas peticiones recién se realice una acción.

Clase donde instancia Volley y estarán los métodos de agregar a la pila

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new Credenciales());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}}
```

Este es el metodo donde ejecuto las consultas ubicado en mi MainActivity

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    showpDialog();
    for (int i = 0; i < nVeces; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nVeces; j++) {
            {
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //acertado
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //ocurrio un error
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                });
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
            }
        }
        //quiero que luego de que termine de ejecutar todas las peticiones pase a otra actividad
    }
```

Deseo que cuando ya haya terminado de ejecutar las peticiones, pase a otra actividad. El problema es que las peticiones realizan cambios en una bd y si cambio de actividad antes de que se ejecuten todas, no notare los cambios.
¿Como sé cuando la pila ya termino de realizar todas las peticiones? ¿como lo haría?

Comment: Puedes establecer un contador que envies con la peticion y devuelvas en el onResponse, en el momento que este dato de la respuesta coincida con el limite superior de tus n repeticiones el ciclo habra finalizado.

Comment: podrias explicarlo con lineas de codigo tu idea? soy nuevo usando Volley me encuentro investigando todo al respecto

Comment: la peticion solo responde un JSON, estoy consumiendo una API que solo le envias la url y te devuelve un JSON ya definido

Comment: Si el json viene de una api esta solución no te sirve, en ese caso dependerá de si la respuesta de la api te permite diferenciar el request que la realizó (normalmente si), de modo que tendrías que analizar el json de vuelta y ver cuando se corresponde a la última petición. Sino puedes intentar crear un contador fuera del bucle que incrementes en el onResponse, ya que sólo entra en este método cuando hay respuesta, y cuando sea igual al total de peticiones habrá terminado; es una idea, nunca lo he intentado porque suelo traerme el dato en el response.

Comment: gracias me has dado una idea, espero funcione saludos